# Why is NSArray access faster with no optimization (-O0 ) then with (-O1, -O2, -O3, -Os, -Ofast)?

Tags: objective-c, performance, cocoa, nsmutablearray, nsarray

#### Abstract

The average access time for NSArray from my tests is fastest using -O0. My test code accesses every element in array for all arrays of length 0 to 10000.

#### Loop for each array:

```
start = mach_absolute_time();
for (string in array){}
arrayDur = mach_absolute_time() - start;
```

#### Access Time Per Element:

- -O0 ~7ns
- -O1 ~12ns
- -O2 ~12ns
- -O3 ~12ns
- -Os ~12ns
- -Ofast ~12ns

#### Graph:

Average access times at different lengths of array

[image: Blue = -O0, Red = -Ofast]

Where blue is -O0, red is -Ofast, the x axis is elements in the array, and the y axis is the average time in ns to access an element.

#### Question:

Aggressive optimization (-Ofast) should be faster or as fast as no optimization (-O0) yet this shows, for NSArray, that optimization is in fact slowing down access times. Why is that, and how could this be considered an optimization?

Comment: According to [this post on clang-developers](http://clang-developers.42468.n3.nabble.com/Left-over-empty-loop-after-optimization-td4035795.html), there may be a bug in the optimizations related to deleting empty loops.  Are the results the same if you perform some pointless operation inside the loop?

Comment: When I have it preform work (increment an integer by 1) inside the loop the problem still exists.

Comment: Apparently Apple does some strange stuff with Arrays. I found this http://ridiculousfish.com/blog/posts/array.html which shows some weird performance data on arrays. It doesn't talk about optimization options but my guess is that somehow the stuff they're doing below the hood might get messed up by the compiler optimizations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To turn manecosta's comment into an answer:

Although your post is quite specific, I think you'll find that NSArray internally optimises itself based on the number of elements it contains among other things.

Checkout this great post by on the [ridiculous fish.com blog](http://ridiculousfish.com/blog/posts/array.html), observing a number of oddities with NSArray

One of the takeaways from the blog post is this:

> So it sure looks like CFArray is switching data structure implementations around 30,000 elements. And I believe there's lots more implementations that I haven't discovered, for smaller arrays and for immutable arrays.

Comment: It's a nice hypothesis, but it shouldn't be the case. All the trickery in NSArray is behind the library boundary and already compiled. I think we'll need assembly output from the testcase to get anywhere on this question (and/or do more array accesses per loop iteration to focus on that aspect).